# Calling a jQuery Dialog without a DIV

Tags: jquery-ui, html, jquery-ui-dialog

Is it possible to create a popup without being based on a div.
Example, I have a the following DIV:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Info">
    <p>This is a test</p>
</div>
```

Instead of calling a dialog like this:

```
$("#dialog").dialog();
```

I would like to call like this:

```
 $("This is a test").dialog();
```

How would it be possible?

Thank you, 
Regards.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can call it like this:

```
 $("<div>This is a test</div>").dialog();
```

Answer (score -1):

To test for a string and, if found, do something (replace the `hover` function `alert("Found");` with whatever you want to do):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    if ($("#dialog p").text("This is a test")) {
        $("#dialog p").hover(function() {
            alert("Found");
        });
    }
});
</script>
```